# Comparing integers and creating the smallest integer possible from the digits of the given integers

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I need to write the following method: accepts two integer parameters and returns an integer.  If either integer is not a 4 digit number than the method should return the smaller integer.  Otherwise, the method should return a four digit integer made up of the smallest digit in the thousands place, hundreds place, tens place and ones place. We cannot turn the integers into Strings, or use lists, or arrays.

For example biggestLoser(6712,1234) returns 1212
For example biggestLoser(19,8918) returns 19

Here's how I've started to write it:

```
public static int biggestLoser(int a, int b){
    if(a<9999 || b<9999){
        if(a<b)
            return a;
        else if(b<a)
            return b;
    }
    int at=a/1000;
    int ah=a%1000/100;
    int an=a%100/10;
    int ae=a%10;
    int bt=b/1000;
    int bh=b%1000/100;
    int bn=b%100/10;
    int be=a%10;
    if(at<bt && ah<bh && an<bn && ae<be)
        return at*1000+ah*100+an*10+ae;
    else if(at<bt && ah<bh && an<bn && be<ae)
        return at*1000+ah*100+an*10+be;
    else if(at<bt&& ah<bh && bn<an && ae<be)
    else return at*1000+ah*100+bn*10+ae;
```

However, it looks like I'm going to have to write way too many if statements, is there a shorter way to write the code?

Comment: Why does the first example give 1212 and not 1122?

Comment: @James_D because you're comparing the digits in each place(thousands vs thousands, tens vs tens, etc) not the overall integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int biggestLoser(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 1000 || a >= 10000 || b < 1000 || b >= 10000) {
        return Math.min(a, b);
    } else {
        // both a and b are four digits
        int result = 0 ;
        int multiplier = 1 ;

        for (int digit = 0; digit < 4; digit++) {
            int nextDigit = Math.min(a % 10, b % 10);
            result = result + nextDigit * multiplier  ;
            multiplier = multiplier * 10 ;
            a = a / 10 ;
            b = b / 10 ;
        }

        return result ;
    }
}
```

How does this work? `a % 10` is the remainder when `a` is divided by `10`: in other words it is the least significant digit of `a` (the "ones place").

`a = a / 10` performs *integer* division, so it divides `a` by `10` and ignores any fraction. So `1234` becomes `123`, and on the next iteration `123` becomes `12`, etc. In other words, it discards the "ones place".

So the first time through the loop, you look at the "ones" from `a` and `b`, find the smallest one, and add it to `result`. Then you drop the "ones" from both `a` and `b`. So what used to be the "tens" are now the "ones". The second time through the loop, you get the smallest "ones" again: but this was originally the smallest "tens". You want to add that to `result`, but you need to multiply by `10`. This is the `multiplier`: each time through the loop the multiplier is multiplied by `10`. So each time, you get the smallest "ones", multiply by the correct thing, add to the result, and then drop the "ones" from `a` and `b`.

Just for fun, here's an implementation that needs only one statement (and works if you replace "four digits" with any positive number of digits). You can ask your instructor to explain it ;).

```
public static final int NUM_DIGITS = 4 ;
public static final int MAX = (int) Math.pow(10, NUM_DIGITS) ;
public static final int MIN = MAX / 10 ;


public static int biggestLoser(int a, int b) {
    return (a < MIN || a >= MAX || b < MIN || b >= MAX) ? Math.min(a, b) :
        IntStream.iterate(1, multiplier -> multiplier * 10).limit(NUM_DIGITS)
            .map(multiplier -> Math.min((a / multiplier) % 10, (b / multiplier) % 10) * multiplier )
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: I'm just starting to learn programming and my teacher has not taught us the majority of what you included in your code so I cannot use it. But thank you for taking the time to write it anyway

Comment: What is not to understand? Lists?

Comment: Lists, .get(), .size(), fourDigit(). We're not allowed to use anything like that

Comment: Are you allowed to use  `String`?

Comment: Well `fourDigit()` is just something I defined right there, so presumably you could use that. `List`s and their methods you will see pretty early... But fair enough. Have you seen arrays yet?

Comment: @jafar If the instructor really expects them to use a `String` solution to perform arithmetic, I think the best advice would be to quit the class and find a new instructor...

Comment: If you are not allowed to use any thing except `if`s and basic arithmetic, continue what you started. Else, `List` and `arrays` should be used if `String`s are disallowed.

Comment: `for` or `while` loops?

Comment: @James_D, loops will results in using collections of some sort.

Comment: @James_D we have used for and while. We can also use Math.min()

Comment: @James_D thank you so much for everything!! You're a savior :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer

```
public static int biggestLoser(int a, int b) {
        if (a < 1000 || b < 1000) {
            if (a < b)
                return a;
            else
                return b;
        }

        int val = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> data1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (a > 0) {
            data1.add(a % 10);
            a /= 10;
        }
        Collections.reverse(data1);
        ArrayList<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (b > 0) {
            data2.add(b % 10);
            b /= 10;
        }
        Collections.reverse(data2);
        val = ((data1.get(0) < data2.get(0)) ? data1.get(0) : data2.get(0))
                * 1000
                + ((data1.get(1) < data2.get(1)) ? data1.get(1) : data2.get(1))
                * 100
                + ((data1.get(2) < data2.get(2)) ? data1.get(2) : data2.get(2))
                * 10
                + ((data1.get(3) < data2.get(3)) ? data1.get(3) : data2.get(3));

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Same misinterpretation I had initially: see comments under question. `biggestLoser(6712, 1234)` returns `1122` in this implementation, not `1212`.

Comment: as you mentioned you want smallest integer, i think 1122 is smaller than 1212

Comment: Well, I didn't mention it, the OP did. But she clarifies the requirement in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, i missed comment, here is the correct answer, and please remove negative marking

Comment: So, you post an incorrect answer, argue when it's politely pointed out to you, and expect not to get downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Using `String` and `StringBuilder`

```
public class Test
{

 public static void main(String []args)
 {
    System.out.println(biggestLooser(6712,1234));
 }
 public static int biggestLooser(int _a, int _b)
 {
     String a = String.valueOf(_a);
     String b = String.valueOf(_b);
     StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();

     if(a.length() < b.length()) return Integer.parseInt(a);
     else if(b.length() < a.length()) return Integer.parseInt(b);
     else if(a.length() >= 4 && b.length() >= 4)
     {
        for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
        {
            char ch = '\0';
            if(a.charAt(a.length() - i) < b.charAt(b.length() - i))
                ch = a.charAt(a.length() - i);
            else ch = b.charAt(b.length() - i);
            c.append(ch);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(c.toString());
     }
     else return -1;
 }
}
//ouput: 1212
```

Answer (score 0):

> maybe it is stupid but try to take advantage of String ( .charAt(int index) )and Integer ( .parseInt( String value ) ) methods , maybe this example help you :

```
    int x=145;
    int y=826;
    //to know which number have the biggest tens 
    String a=x+"";
    String b=y+"";

    if(Integer.parseInt(a.charAt(1)+"")>Integer.parseInt(b.charAt(1)+""))
    {
        System.out.println("The number which have the biggest tens is "+a);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The number which have the biggest tens is "+b);
    }
```